# How to view complete contents of NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, xcode6.1, ios8.1

I have an app where I store all of the user preferences in NSUserDefaults.  I would like to be able to see (for debugging purposes) the complete contents of the NSUserDefaults file.

Can it be done without providing each of the keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Can it be done without providing each of the keys?
```

You can use [dictionaryRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/dictionaryRepresentation) of `NSUserDefaults` like that below example:-

```
NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[def setObject:@"test1" forKey:@"test1"];
[def setObject:@"test2" forKey:@"test2"];
NSLog(@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]dictionaryRepresentation]);
```

*EDIT:-*

When use `dictionaryRepresentation` it will print the complete information of user default, including extra value which is added in the defaults.

Below is the output of above code. Also you can see the value in the last which is extra included in the user defaults :-

```
AppleAntiAliasingThreshold = 4;
    AppleGCIdleTimeInterval = "1.0";
    AppleLanguages =     (
        en,
        fr,
        de,
        "zh-Hans",
        "zh-Hant",
        ja,
        es,
        it,
        nl,
        ko,
        pt,
        "pt-PT",
        da,
        fi,
        nb,
        sv,
        ru,
        pl,
        tr,
        ar,
        th,
        cs,
        hu,
        ca,
        hr,
        el,
        he,
        ro,
        sk,
        uk,
        id,
        ms,
        vi
    );
    AppleLocale = "en_US";
    AppleMeasurementUnits = Inches;
    AppleMetricUnits = 0;
    AppleMiniaturizeOnDoubleClick = 0;
    AppleShowScrollBars = Always;
    AppleTextDirection = 0;
    AppleUserLanguages = 1;
    Country = US;
    MultipleSessionEnabled = 1;
    NSBoldSystemFont = ".LucidaGrandeUI-Bold";
    NSButtonDelay = "0.4";
    NSButtonPeriod = "0.075";
    NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode = YES;
    NSDragAutoscrollAreaWidth = "5.0";
    NSDragCancelLimit = "100000.0";
    NSDraggingAutoscrollDelay = "0.4";
    NSEnableAutoCollapseOutlineDuringDragsDefault = NO;
    NSEnableAutoExpandOutlineDuringDragsDefault = YES;
    NSFixedPitchFont = "Menlo-Regular";
    NSFixedPitchFontSize = 11;
    NSFont = Helvetica;
    NSFontSize = 12;
    NSInputServerLaunchTimeout = 60;
    NSInterfaceStyle = macintosh;
    NSLanguages =     (
        en,
        fr,
        de,
        "zh-Hans",
        "zh-Hant",
        ja,
        es,
        it,
        nl,
        ko,
        pt,
        "pt-PT",
        da,
        fi,
        nb,
        sv,
        ru,
        pl,
        tr,
        ar,
        th,
        cs,
        hu,
        ca,
        hr,
        el,
        he,
        ro,
        sk,
        uk,
        id,
        ms,
        vi
    );
    NSMargins = "72 72 90 90";
    NSMenuFlashCount = 3;
    NSMenuScrollingOffset = 3;
    NSMenuScrollingSpeed = 5;
    NSNavPanelFileLastListModeForOpenModeKey = 1;
    NSNavPanelFileListModeForOpenMode2 = 1;
    NSNavPanelSidebarKeyForOpen =     (
    );
    NSNavPanelSidebarKeyForSave =     (
    );
    NSNavRecentPlaces =     (
        "~/Documents",
        "~/Documents/sample Project/learning_iOS",
        "~/Desktop/firstPage",
        "~/Desktop/SoftwareDepotIssue",
        "~/Desktop"
    );
    NSPreferredSpellServerVendors =     {
        English = "NeXT-OpenStep";
    };
    NSPreferredWebServices =     {
        NSWebServicesProviderWebSearch =         {
            NSDefaultDisplayName = Google;
            NSProviderIdentifier = "com.google.www";
        };
    };
    NSQuotedKeystrokeBinding = "^q";
    NSRequireAutoCollapseOutlineAfterDropsDefault = NO;
    NSResetIncrementalSearchOnFailure = YES;
    NSScrollAnimationEnabled = YES;
    NSScrollerButtonAcceleration = 8;
    NSScrollerButtonDelay = "0.5";
    NSScrollerButtonPeriod = "0.05";
    NSScrollerHasSeparateArrows = YES;
    NSScrollerKnobCount = 2;
    NSScrollerKnobDelay = "0.001";
    NSSmartCMYKColorConversion = YES;
    NSSystemFont = ".LucidaGrandeUI";
    NSSystemFontSize = 13;
    NSUIHeartBeatCycle = "0.03";
    NSUseCocoaInputServers = YES;
    NSUserDictionaryReplacementItems =     (
    );
    NSWindowResizeTime = ".20";
    NavPanelFileListModeForOpenMode = 1;
    SGTRecentFileSearches =     (
                {
            attributes =             (
                kMDItemDisplayName
            );
            enforceStrictMatch = 0;
            exactMatch = 0;
            name = istsu;
            scope = 4;
            type = "com.apple.finder";
            values =             (
                istsu
            );
        }
    );
    WebKitAVFoundationEnabled = 1;
    WebKitAccelerated2dCanvasEnabled = 0;
    WebKitAcceleratedCompositingEnabled = 1;
    WebKitAcceleratedDrawingEnabled = 0;
    WebKitAllowAnimatedImageLoopingPreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitAllowAnimatedImagesPreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs = 1;
    WebKitAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = 1;
    WebKitApplicationCacheDefaultOriginQuota = 9223372036854775807;
    WebKitApplicationCacheTotalQuota = 9223372036854775807;
    WebKitApplicationChromeModeEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitAsynchronousSpellCheckingEnabled = 0;
    WebKitAuthorAndUserStylesEnabledPreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitBackForwardCacheExpirationIntervalKey = 1800;
    WebKitBackspaceKeyNavigationEnabled = 1;
    WebKitCSSCompositingEnabled = 1;
    WebKitCSSCustomFilterEnabled = 1;
    WebKitCSSGridLayoutEnabled = 0;
    WebKitCSSRegionsEnabled = 1;
    WebKitCacheModelPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitCanvasUsesAcceleratedDrawing = 0;
    WebKitCursiveFont = "Apple Chancery";
    WebKitDNSPrefetchingEnabled = 0;
    WebKitDOMPasteAllowedPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitDatabasesEnabledPreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitDefaultFixedFontSize = 13;
    WebKitDefaultFontSize = 16;
    WebKitDefaultTextEncodingName = "ISO-8859-1";
    WebKitDeveloperExtrasEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitDiagnosticLoggingEnabled = 0;
    WebKitDisplayImagesKey = 1;
    WebKitEditableLinkBehavior = 0;
    WebKitEnableInheritURIQueryComponent = 0;
    WebKitExperimentalNotificationsEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitFantasyFont = Papyrus;
    WebKitFixedFont = Courier;
    WebKitFrameFlatteningEnabled = 0;
    WebKitFullScreenEnabled = 0;
    WebKitHiddenPageCSSAnimationSuspensionEnabled = 0;
    WebKitHiddenPageDOMTimerThrottlingEnabled = 0;
    WebKitHyperlinkAuditingEnabled = 1;
    WebKitJavaEnabled = 1;
    WebKitJavaScriptCanAccessClipboard = 0;
    WebKitJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = 1;
    WebKitJavaScriptEnabled = 1;
    WebKitJavaScriptExperimentsEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitKerningAndLigaturesEnabledByDefault = 1;
    WebKitLoadSiteIconsKey = 0;
    WebKitLocalFileContentSniffingEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitLocalStorageEnabledPreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitLowPowerVideoAudioBufferSizeEnabled = 0;
    WebKitMediaPlaybackAllowsInline = 1;
    WebKitMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture = 0;
    WebKitMinimumFontSize = 0;
    WebKitMinimumLogicalFontSize = 9;
    WebKitNotificationsEnabled = 1;
    WebKitOfflineWebApplicationCacheEnabled = 0;
    WebKitPDFDisplayMode = 1;
    WebKitPDFScaleFactor = 0;
    WebKitPageCacheSupportsPluginsPreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitPictographFont = "Apple Color Emoji";
    WebKitPlugInSnapshottingEnabled = 0;
    WebKitPluginsEnabled = 1;
    WebKitPrivateBrowsingEnabled = 0;
    WebKitQTKitEnabled = 1;
    WebKitRegionBasedColumnsEnabled = 0;
    WebKitRequestAnimationFrameEnabled = 1;
    WebKitRespectStandardStyleKeyEquivalents = 0;
    WebKitSansSerifFont = Helvetica;
    WebKitScreenFontSubstitutionEnabled = 0;
    WebKitSerifFont = Times;
    WebKitShouldDisplayCaptions = 0;
    WebKitShouldDisplaySubtitles = 0;
    WebKitShouldDisplayTextDescriptions = 0;
    WebKitShouldPrintBackgroundsPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitShouldRespectImageOrientation = 0;
    WebKitShowDebugBorders = 0;
    WebKitShowRepaintCounter = 0;
    WebKitShowsToolTipOverTruncatedText = 0;
    WebKitShowsURLsInToolTips = 0;
    WebKitShrinksStandaloneImagesToFit = 0;
    WebKitSpatialNavigationEnabled = 0;
    WebKitStandardFont = Times;
    WebKitStorageBlockingPolicy = 0;
    WebKitSuppressesIncrementalRendering = 0;
    WebKitTabToLinksPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitTextAreasAreResizable = 0;
    WebKitTextDirectionSubmenuInclusionBehaviorPreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitUseLegacyTextAlignPositionedElementBehavior = 0;
    WebKitUsePreHTML5ParserQuirks = 0;
    WebKitUseSiteSpecificSpoofing = 0;
    WebKitUserStyleSheetEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitUserStyleSheetLocationPreferenceKey = "";
    WebKitUsesEncodingDetector = 0;
    WebKitUsesPageCachePreferenceKey = 1;
    WebKitWantsBalancedSetDefersLoadingBehavior = 0;
    WebKitWebArchiveDebugModeEnabledPreferenceKey = 0;
    WebKitWebAudioEnabled = 0;
    WebKitWebGLEnabled = 0;
    WebKitWebSecurityEnabled = 1;
    WebKitXSSAuditorEnabled = 1;
    WebKitZoomsTextOnly = 1;
    "com.apple.AppleModemSettingTool.LastCountryCode" = US;
    "com.apple.ColorSync.Devices" =     {
        "Device.cmra.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000533630" =         {
            DeviceDescriptions =             {
                "en_US" = "NO NAME";
            };
            FactoryProfiles =             {
                555810816 =                 {
                    DeviceModeDescriptions =                     {
                        "en_US" = Default;
                    };
                    DeviceProfileURL = "/System/Library/Frameworks/ICADevices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Camera RGB Profile.icc";
                };
                DeviceDefaultProfileID = 555810816;
            };
        };
        "Device.cmra.30303441-3030-3930-4637-393830304637" =         {
            DeviceDescriptions =             {
                "en_US" = "Lumia 520";
            };
            FactoryProfiles =             {
                555810816 =                 {
                    DeviceModeDescriptions =                     {
                        "en_US" = Default;
                    };
                    DeviceProfileURL = "/System/Library/Frameworks/ICADevices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Camera RGB Profile.icc";
                };
                DeviceDefaultProfileID = 555810816;
            };
        };
        "Device.cmra.37616133-3566-6339-6362-303662336639" =         {
            DeviceDescriptions =             {
                "en_US" = iPhone;
            };
            FactoryProfiles =             {
                555810816 =                 {
                    DeviceModeDescriptions =                     {
                        "en_US" = Default;
                    };
                    DeviceProfileURL = "/System/Library/Frameworks/ICADevices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Camera RGB Profile.icc";
                };
                DeviceDefaultProfileID = 555810816;
            };
        };
    };
    "com.apple.TimeZonePref.Last_Selected_City" =     (
        "37.36883",
        "-122.0363",
        0,
        "America/Los_Angeles",
        US,
        Sunnyvale,
        "U.S.A.",
        Sunnyvale,
        "U.S.A.",
        "DEPRECATED IN 10.6"
    );
    "com.apple.preferences.timezone.selected_city" =     {
        CountryCode = US;
        GeonameID = 5400075;
        Latitude = "37.36883";
        LocalizedNames =         {
            ar = "\U0633\U0627\U0646\U064a\U0641\U064a\U0644";
            ca = Sunnyvale;
            cs = Sunnyvale;
            da = Sunnyvale;
            de = Sunnyvale;
            el = Sunnyvale;
            en = Sunnyvale;
            es = Sunnyvale;
            fi = Sunnyvale;
            fr = Sunnyvale;
            he = "\U05e1\U05d0\U05e0\U05d9\U05d5\U05d5\U05dc";
            hr = Sunnyvale;
            hu = Sunnyvale;
            id = Sunnyvale;
            it = Sunnyvale;
            ja = "\U30b5\U30cb\U30fc\U30d9\U30fc\U30eb";
            ko = "\Uc11c\Ub2c8\Ubca0\Uc77c";
            ms = Sunnyvale;
            nb = Sunnyvale;
            nl = Sunnyvale;
            pl = Sunnyvale;
            pt = Sunnyvale;
            "pt-PT" = Sunnyvale;
            ro = Sunnyvale;
            ru = "\U0421\U0430\U043d\U043d\U0438\U0432\U0435\U0439\U043b";
            sk = Sunnyvale;
            sv = Sunnyvale;
            th = Sunnyvale;
            tr = Sunnyvale;
            uk = "\U0421\U0430\U043d\U043d\U0456\U0432\U0435\U0439\U043b";
            vi = Sunnyvale;
            "zh-Hans" = "\U6851\U5c3c\U7ef4\U5c14";
            "zh-Hant" = "\U6851\U5c3c\U7dad\U723e";
        };
        Longitude = "-122.0363";
        Name = Sunnyvale;
        Population = 140081;
        RegionalCode = CA;
        TimeZoneName = "America/Los_Angeles";
        Version = 1;
    };
    "com.apple.springing.delay" = "0.5";
    "com.apple.springing.enabled" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.enableSecondaryClick" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fiveFingerPinchSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerHorizSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerPinchSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.fourFingerVertSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.momentumScroll" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.pinchGesture" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.rotateGesture" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.scrollBehavior" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerDragGesture" = 0;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerHorizSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerTapGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.threeFingerVertSwipeGesture" = 2;
    "com.apple.trackpad.twoFingerDoubleTapGesture" = 1;
    "com.apple.trackpad.twoFingerFromRightEdgeSwipeGesture" = 3;
    "com.apple.trackpad.version" = 5;
    "com.apple.updatesettings_did_disable_ftp" = 1;
    test1 = test1;
    test2 = test2;
```

Comment: Thank you... works like a champ!